# ubuntu 23.04 (original) is not installed with vmware and virtualbox

Tags: virtualization, vmware, ubuntu-mate, 23.04

good afternoon

I have a problem with both vmware and virtualbox, if I install an ubuntu flavor that is 23.04 in a vmware virtual machine, it lets it install until the end, however if it is ubuntu 23.04 with the new installer, it hangs and It won't let me install the virtual machine (in 22.04 it does let it install), would there be any solution to directly install the 23.04 continuous release, the normal one or would I have to do it from the network [since 22.04 LTS]?

my computer is a second generation i5, ubuntu mate 20.04 with vmware 17.02, the one i am using with windows in a course is a third generation i5, windows 10 and virtualbox 7 (both are not upgradeable to windows 11)

Thank you very much and receive a greeting.

Comment: You can try to start from a compressed image file of Ubuntu Server according to [this link to the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). Please read the whole thread before selecting method.

Comment: It works for me with VirtualBox hosted by Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS in a Dell Precision with a forth generation i7 processor and 32 GB RAM. It should work with Ubuntu Server, maybe you get problems if you install ubuntu-desktop, but a smaller desktop, for example xubuntu-minimal, the package `xubuntu-core`, might work (it depends not only on the CPU but also on the RAM, how much you can give to the virtual machines).